# Подпись приложения для appgallery

Tags: android, google-play

Есть приложение, ключи которого (если я правильно понимаю) [хранятся в гугле](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423).

Нужно вылить это приложение в appgallery. Но имеется следующая проблема:

Если на смартфоне стоит 2 маркета, например и Google и Huawei одновременно, возникнет проблема конфликта ключей: обновление в одном маркете удалит все данные приложения, если оно было скачено/обновлено в другом.

Кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой? Как лучше поступить в такой ситуации?